# Returning an reference variable of a class

Tags: java

In the getNextNode() I am returning a reference variable of a class what does that mean???

```
class Node1{
    private String data;
    private Node1 nextNode;
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

public Node1 getNextNode() {
        return nextNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can somebody explain the above code???

Comment: It is a DS that can be used to create single LinkedList.

Comment: The phrase "a reference variable of a class" doesn't appear in the Java Language Specification, though each of those words appears individually.  If you would like a definition of any of those words, maybe ask for that instead.

Comment: Aniket you are exactly right...I created a node,,,but i want to Iterate for various nodes,,,Thats why i wanted to know how this will be heplfull in acheiving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code:

```
class Node1{
    private String data;
    private Node1 nextNode;
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

public Node1 getNextNode() {
        return nextNode;
    }
}
```

You have an object called Node1. You can make new Node1 objects by calling

```
Node1 n1 = new Node1();
```

this means n1 contains all the private fields you set.

n1 has a private `Node1` field `nextNode` which is only accessible within this class. Other classes cannot modify or retrieve this field.

In order for outside classes to retrieve this `nextNode` field you have a getter method `getNextNode()` which returns to whatever class that called it a copy of that private `nextNode` field.

This is the benefit of `OOP`.

Comment: if suppose if i want to create one more instance of a class to store a new value then how should i make use of the above method

Comment: that method does not set the values of the private fields you will need setter methods eg: public void setData(string str){
this.Data = str;
}

Comment: ill post myentire code in a different question

Answer (score 1):

```
Node1 node = node1.getNextNode();
```

Here `node` will copy the reference value of `nextNode` which will be pointing to a `Node1` object.

Comment: Actually i wanted to acheive linked list implementation by using this,,,,i inserted one data into a node,,,but forstoring the next data i should point tothe same class,,,but with a different instance of the class,,,can that be done???

Answer (score 1):

> In the getNextNode() am a returning a reference variable of a class
>   what does that mean???

This means that the caller of the `getNextNode()` method will refer to the same Node1 (`nextNode`) object. Any changes made to the returned value by the caller will directly reflect in your current instance of Node1.

Answer (score 0):

In the above method, getNextNode, you are returning a 'reference' that is pointing to an object of type Node1.